# Spark sql.DataFrame filter function not working as expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, dataframe, pyspark

I have an pyspark.sql.DataFrame  with some rows, if I try to take some of them I can see is populated as expected, for example:

`train_df.take(20)`

returning me:

```
[Row(entityId=u'7179b9467f825a5bbb748ea6226b12137e23a19f', event=u'preferences-tags', targetEntityId=u'angriff'),
Row(entityId=u'7179b9467f825a5bbb748ea6226b12137e23a19f', event=u'preferences-tags', targetEntityId=u'schiff'),
Row(entityId=u'7179b9467f825a5bbb748ea6226b12137e23a19f', event=u'preferences-communityId', targetEntityId=u', ... ]
```

And I want to filter them by one of the fields, for example where `event` = `preferences-tags`, using the filter function as below:

```
PRIMARY_EVENT_NAME = 'preferences-tags'
rating = train_df.filter("event = '%s'" % (PRIMARY_EVENT_NAME))
```

But it seems it doesnt filter them properly, as returning 0 results

```
rating.count()
# 0 is returned
```

I used filter function with same syntax and logic in other parts of my code and it performs just as expected, what's wrong here?

Comment: `filter` takes a function, so I don't see why you think a string will do anything

Comment: train_df is a pyspark.sql.DataFrame and filter accepts a string of SQL expression as a parameter

Comment: Ah, I see what you're asking now. If you are using strings, then have you tried `LIKE` or `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: I tried `LIKE` and still returning 0, `==` is not a valid sql operator so returns an error.